# Access to a newly created folder is denied

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, asp.net-4.0

I'm writing a file on a network drive into a new folder.

```
string directory=@"\\dir\test\"
string folderName = "testFolder " + DateTimeOffset.Now.UtcDateTime.ToString().Replace("/","-").Replace(":","-");

string newPath = Path.Combine(directory, folderName);

        if (!Directory.Exists(newPath))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(newPath);
        }
        if (!File.Exists(newPath))
        {
            using (System.IO.FileStream fs = File.Create(newPath))
            {
                fs.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            }
        }
```

on line: `using (System.IO.FileStream fs = File.Create(newPath))` - it errors out saying:

> Access to the path '\dir\test\testFolder 3-19-2012 11-58-43 PM' is
>   denied.

I've to create a directory with DirectorySecurity allowing read and write. still receiving an error.

I've been following the following topic to create folder and file:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/as2f1fez.aspx

I'm able to write to the directory `@"\\dir\test\"` with no problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the same `newPath` for the directory and file.